# Easier way to reshape a file (panel format)

Tags: r, pandas, stata

Dears, I need to reshape a series to a panel model, I thougt that would faster doing myself, but there's too much data to fix, [this is how I want to put my data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MDquO.png) [this is how it is] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/t2DNr.png). I want to do my reaserch by RStudio, can anyone help me to reshape?

Ps: As I'm starting to do my tests, I'm open to try by Pandas or Stata.

I only tried through Excel.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bV2ly.jpg)

Comment: [reshape data from long to wide in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890584/how-to-reshape-data-from-long-to-wide-format)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We cannot read data into R from images. In future please [make questions reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) by including a small representative dataset in a plain text format - for example the output from `dput(yourdata)`, if that is not too large.